# perl regex negative-lookbehind detect file lacking final linefeed

Tags: regex, perl, newline, eof, negative-lookbehind

The following code uses `tail` to test whether the last line of a file fails to culminate in a newline (linefeed, LF).

```sh
> printf 'aaa\nbbb\n' | test -n "$(tail -c1)" && echo pathological last line
> printf 'aaa\nbbb'   | test -n "$(tail -c1)" && echo pathological last line
pathological last line 
>
```

One can test for the same condition by using perl, a positive lookbehind regex, and `unless`, as follows. This is based on the notion that, if a file ends with newline, the character immediately preceding end-of-file will be `\n` by definition.

(Recall that the `-n0` flag causes perl to "slurp" the entire file as a single record. Thus, there is only one `$`, the end of the file.)

```sh
> printf 'aaa\nbbb\n' | perl -n0 -e 'print "pathological last line\n" unless m/(?<=\n)$/;'
> printf 'aaa\nbbb'   | perl -n0 -e 'print "pathological last line\n" unless m/(?<=\n)$/;'
pathological last line
>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using `if` rather than `unless`, and negative lookbehind? The following fails, in that the regex seems to **always** match:

```sh
> printf 'aaa\nbbb\n' | perl -n0 -e 'print "pathological last line\n" if m/(?<!\n)$/;'
pathological last line
> printf 'aaa\nbbb'   | perl -n0 -e 'print "pathological last line\n" if m/(?<!\n)$/;'
pathological last line
>
```

Why does my regex always match, even when the end-of-file is preceded by newline? I am trying to test for an end-of-file that is **not** preceded by newline.

Comment: `-0` isn't slurp mode, `-0777` is

Answer (score 2):

`/(?<=\n)$/` is a weird and expensive way of doing `/\n$/`.

`/\n$/` means `/\n(?=\n?\z)/`, so it's a weird and expensive way of doing `/\n\z/`.

A few approaches:

```
perl -n0777e'print "pathological last line\n" if !/\n\z/'
```

```
perl -n0777e'print "pathological last line\n" if /(?<!\n)\z/'
```

```
perl -n0777e'print "pathological last line\n" if substr($_, -1) ne "\n"'
```

```
perl -ne'$ll=$_; END { print "pathological last line\n" if $ll !~ /\n\z/ }'
```

The last solution avoids slurping the entire file.

---

> *Why does my regex always match, even when the end-of-file is preceded by newline?*

Because you mistakenly think that `$` only matches at the end of the string. Use `\z` for that.

Comment: Maybe explain that "0777" turns on slurp mode? You said so in your comment to the original question, but more readers will see it if you mention it in your answer. (Which would be a good thing because I, for one, did not know that.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a strong reason for using a regular expression for his job? Practicing regular expressions for example? If not, I think a simpler approach is to just use a `while` loop that tests for `eof` and remembers the latest character read. Something like this might do the job.

```
 perl -le'while (!eof()) { $previous = getc(\*ARGV) } 
          if ($previous ne "\n") { print "pathological last line!" }'
```

PS: ikegami's comment about my solution being slow is well-taken. (Thanks for the helpful edit, too!) So I wondered if there's a way to read the file backwards. As it turns out, CPAN has a module for just that. After installing it, I came up with this:

```
perl -le 'use File::ReadBackwards; 
          my $bw = File::ReadBackwards->new(shift @ARGV);
          print "pathological last line" if substr($bw->readline, -1) ne "\n"'
```

That should work efficiently, even very large files. And when I come back to read it a year later, I will more likely understand it  than I would with the regular-expression approach.

Answer (score 0):

The hidden context of my request was a perl script to "clean" a text file used in the TeX/LaTeX environment. This is why I wanted to slurp. 
(I mistakenly thought that "laser focus" on a problem, recommended by stackoverflow, meant editing out the context.)

Thanks to the responses, here is an improved draft of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings; use 5.18.2;
# Loop slurp: 
$/ = undef;     # input record separator: entire file is a single record.
# a "trivial line" looks blank, consists exclusively of whitespace, but is not necessarily a pure newline=linefeed=LF.
while (<>) {
    s/^\s*$/\n/mg;          # convert any trivial line to a pure LF. Unlike \z, $ works with /m multiline.
    s/[\n][\n]+/\n\n/g; # exactly 2 blank lines (newlines) separate paragraphs. Like cat -s
    s/^[\n]+//;             # first line is visible or "nontrivial."
    s/[\n]+\z/\n/;      # last  line is visible or "nontrivial."
    print STDOUT;
    print "\n" unless m/\n\z/; # IF detect pathological last line, i.e., not ending in LF, THEN append LF. 
}
```

And here is how it works, when named zz.pl. First a messy file, then how it looks after zz.pl gets through with it:

```
bash: printf '  \n \r   \naaa\n \t \n  \n  \nbb\n\n\n\n    \t' 


aaa



bb



        bash: 
bash: 
bash: printf '  \n \r   \naaa\n \t \n  \n  \nbb\n\n\n\n    \t' | zz.pl
aaa

bb
bash:
```